# Custom Array to Entity Type form using Data Transformer

Tags: symfony, ssis

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $categoryArray = $this->getTreeArray(); 
    $builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'CategoryBundle:Category',
        'label' => 'Categories',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true,
        'empty_value' => NULL,
        'choices' => $customcategoryArray,
    ));
}
```

I want to supply customized tree array to entity type form field . The Entity type have multiselect attribute.
The Solution is hidden in Data Transformer , i tryed my best but i can't do this thing . I need help all of you , please help me.